# ExtJs problem in filtering store

Tags: extjs, filter, store

I'm having trouble in store filtering. My filter function is working fine and returning true/false as expected.. but in the end all the records are filtered out!!
The xstore is reference to store of Grid. I have also used the main store variable.. but no luck!! Any help is appriciated.

```
xstore.filterBy(function(rec){

        app_rec = rec.get('APPNAME').toUpperCase(); //Record's value that needs to be checked'

        Ext.each(elems,function(el){ //For each record, it checks 7 (dynamic) elements 
            //var ischecked = Ext.get(Ext.getCmp(el.id).teamName+'cb').dom.checked;

            if(Ext.getCmp(el.id).teamName.toUpperCase() == app_rec)
            {// If Element's attribute 'teamname' is matched then check if element's chkbox is chked/unched' 
                var ischecked = Ext.get(Ext.getCmp(el.id).teamName+'cb').dom.checked; //get the checkbox
                //alert("app_rec: "+app_rec+"panelTeam: " + Ext.getCmp(el.id).teamName.toUpperCase()+"isChecked: "+ischecked );
                if(ischecked) //if isChecked... keep record.. below alert if working as expected
                { alert("return true"+"app_rec: "+app_rec+"panelTeam: " + Ext.getCmp(el.id).teamName.toUpperCase()+"isChecked: "+ischecked); 
                    return true;} 
                else //Else avoid record
                { //alert("return false"); 
                    return false;}
            }

        });
```

Thanks,
Tushar Saxena

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.each` is different from a regular JavaScript for loop in that you can return false within the each call to stop iteration. The Ext.each documentation mentions this:

> If the supplied function returns false, iteration stops and this
>   method returns the current index.

So when you're returning from within the each call, you're not returning true/false to the `filterBy` function like you expect, but to the `each` function.

Try keeping a handle on `isChecked` outside of the each loop, and then return true/false based on what was found inside the each function:

```
// excluded your other code to highlight area around Ext.each call

var isChecked = false;

Ext.each(elems, function(el){ 
    if(Ext.getCmp(el.id).teamName.toUpperCase() == app_rec) {
        ischecked = Ext.get(Ext.getCmp(el.id).teamName+'cb').dom.checked;

        // can exit early if isChecked is true
        if(isChecked){
            return false; // this will exit the Ext.each method
        }
    }
});

// if this is true, filterBy will include the record
return isChecked;
```